# Assign number values to certain letters in Excel or OpenOffice

Tags: microsoft-excel, scheduled-tasks, openoffice

I'd like like to know how to assign to some letters a number value for a monthly Hospital schedule. For example:

1. N for night = 12h
2. M for morning = 6h
3. P for afternoon = 6h
4. CS for day off = 6h
5. R for rest = 6h

I can use OpenOffice or Excel. I'm currently using a Mac.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Please clarify better your question: What do you mean by "assign", replace, or get the numbers in a new column? Posting sample data and output would be also useful. Why do you use the tag "scheduled-tasks"?

Answer (score 0):

From Microsoft Excel, you could use a second table to keep an easy record of which letter corresponds to each code. This would ideally live on a separate sheet but could be on the same:

```
Code | Value
------------
   N | 12
   M | 6
   P | 6
  CS | 6
   R | 6
```

In your original table, your **Code** column should probably use data validation to force the user to choose one of these options. Assuming you're using a recent version of Excel, choose `Data > Data Validation > Settings > Allow: List`, then for 'source' choose the first column of your new table.

Finally, your original table could have a 'Time' column which uses a `VLOOKUP` formula to check the time-value of the Code. If you're unfamiliar with vlookup then watch [this](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/VLOOKUP-What-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-5984e27b-4f0d-431e-83b1-7ab062c75493).